# mdadm assembles degraded RAID 5 as RAID 0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, software-raid

I have a four disk RAID 5 set up under kubuntu 16.10. One of the disks failed and I am waiting for a replacement to arrive. However, my computer froze at some point and now mdadm tries to assemble my array as RAID0 instead of RAID5. Previous normal reboots did not have any problems reassembling the degraded array.

There's no difference in array assembly from `mdadm.conf` or by running `mdadm -A --scan`. Both attempt to assemble the array as RAID0.

`mdadm --examine` shows the drives correctly as parts of a RAID5 array with event counts equal on all of them.

I'm afraid to run `mdadm --create --assume-clean` as it issues plenty of warnings on how disk data would be overwritten.

Is there any way I can tell mdadm to assemble the array correctly as RAID5?

Answer (score 0):

`mdadm --assemble --force` worked after stopping and removing the raid0 assembly.